# JVM_Bind when running OSGi application from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, osgi

I have the following problem.

I have a run-configuration (osgi-type) in Eclipse. Once upon a time this run configuration ran fine, without any problems.

Now when I try to run it I get a `java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind` and all the rows printed in the console are printed twice.

I see that the application is started on port xxxx and then a couple of rows later I get the error.

The run-configuration hasn't changed.

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems there is port conflict. Two process trying to run on same port.

Comment: Yes well I was able to figure that much out. The thing is it use to work in the past and now for some reason just won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is due to an application trying to bind to a server port, while the port has already been taken by another application.

You also mention every row in the console is printed twice. This means the application is probably launched twice.

There is not enough information to determine why your run configuration launches the same application twice. You should look at the DEBUG perspective in Eclipse to see whether a single process was launched with two threads.

Comment: I'll give that a try. Still, nothing in the run-configuration has been changed yet this happens...strange as hell if you ask me.

Comment: Found any solution?;)